# File.canWrite is not working as per expectations

Tags: java, java-io

i am trying to check whether a file is writable or not. i have changed the file permission by myself for all users. but if i try to run the program, it show "true" as a response. if i allow the permissions, then also it is showing "true".

Whats is my problem?

```
try
  {

     File file = new File("D:/myproject_log/delivery_report_edr.out"); 

        if(!file.canWrite())
        {
            System.out.println("you can't write!!!");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("you can write!!!");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: You haven't said what you changed the permissions *to*...

Comment: you are doing something wrong in how you think you are setting permissions, your posted code should work as expected if the permissions are set correctly.

Comment: who is the owner of the file and who is running the application?

Comment: through eclipse i am trying to run the application. i myself created the file, but then took out the permission to write in it. all operations i am doing in my local desktop only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working fine. I copied your code and run it twice. First I got **You can write**, then right click on the file folder, go to properties and select **read only** and run the program again and I got **you can't write**

So as per the documentation of the method **canWrite()** it gave me the expected output. Please confirm your settings once again and check.

Comment: i have changed the permissions to "deny" in windows OS. with the same file i am trying to log my entries. but while creating the logger with the same file, i am getting the exception saying java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\myproject_log\delivery_report_edr.out (Access is denied)

Comment: @user1282551 can you say how you are changing the permission?

Comment: in windows, right clicking on the file and then going in properties... there in security tab, i have changed the permission for write by clicking on "deny" option. is it the correct way???

Comment: @user1282551 sorry I can't help you more, but I can say if you change the **General property** of a file to **read-only** then you will get proper outputs.

Comment: The documentation says: "true if and only if the file system actually contains a file denoted by this abstract pathname and the application is allowed to write to the file; false otherwise". In many situations, canWrite returns true even though the application is _not_ allowed to write to the file, so I wouldn't call this confirming to the documentation at all. The documentation really should be clearer that it won't check permissions to the file at all.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [java.nio.file.Files#isWritable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method. as well as File#canWrite ?

Comment: I have had same issue with canWrite giving me incorrect answers when I asked if I can create files into the direction. But your answer has fixed the issue ;)

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. `File.canWrite` considers `new File("C:/Windows/System32/");` to be writable, even for non-admin users. `Files#isWritable` actually checks if the current user is allowed to write.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found that `File.canWrite()` cannot be trusted, especially over network drives, often returning `true` even though a file write will fail or vice-versa. I made my own method that actually tries to write a dummy file to the dir. That is simple to write and foolproof. Maybe they fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a file located in c:\programFiles\folder and the File.canWrite method returned true and i was getting the same exception.
when i changed the permission of write as allowed true for USER defined in security tab of Folder properties, It gave me no exception.